# UICollectionViewFlowLayout minimumLineSpacing not applied to whole collection view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, spacing, flowlayout

I'm creating UIView subclass for calendar, wherein UICollectionView with flow layout is used to display dates. The code is :

```
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        super.draw(rect)
        .
        .

        configureCalendarView()
        .
    }



    func configureCalendarView()
    {
        cellWd = Double(self.frame.size.width)/7.0

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.5
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 0, 0)

        collectionV = UICollectionView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:90, width:self.frame.size.width, height:CGFloat(cellWd * 5 + 3.5)), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionV?.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        collectionV?.isScrollEnabled = false
        collectionV?.register(DayCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID)
        collectionV?.dataSource = self;
        collectionV?.delegate = self;
        collectionV?.backgroundColor = calBgColor  //lightgray
        self.addSubview(collectionV!)
    }
```

Everything is working fine but minimum line spacing is not having any effect between 2nd and 3rd row. Below is the screenshot :

[image]

Whats going wrong ? Any help would greatly be appreciated . Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.5 translates to 0.5point * scale  = pixels.

So if you are running on iphone 6+ 7+ with 3.0 scale, that 0.5 will be 1.5 pixels. And on 2x scale that will be 1 pixel.
To correct this. add this:

layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
This way you guaranteed always get 1 pixel spacing.

Edit:

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0f;

CGFloat collectionWidth = self.frame.size.width;
CGFloat days = 7.0f;
CGFloat spacing = 1.0f;

CGFloat itemHeight = floorf((collectionWidth/days) - spacing;
```

Comment: CGFloat(cellWd * 5 + 3.5))  you must fix the calculation here also ,  + 5.0/screenScale

Comment: tried changing this too, but it just increasing bottom border, as the collectionview height increase( and background color is light gray)

Comment: remove your layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 0, 0), make it UIEdgeInsetsZero . That gives you a constant 1 point (2 pixels) inset from top, thats why it gets added to the bottom instead. If you want the top inset, you need to take that into your calculation also.

Comment: still not working  ^. In fact, if i set minimum line spacing to 1.0 then line appeared as of 0.5. So if I'm setting minimum line spacing to 0.5 it appeared as of 0. So basically, there is difference of 0.5 below second row only.

Comment: There is something wrong with your calculations. If you set it to 1.0 and the line appeared as 0.5, that means you dont have enough total space in the collectionview.frame as the calculations to fit the spacings. So the spacing gets "compressed" together , and depending on your screen pixels, you will see 1 pixel (0.5 as you say it) or 0 pixel (if you set it 0.5 as you say it.)

So , the actual error might be in your sizeForItemAtIndexPath, which you are not showing in your code above. You need to make sure that your cell height is calculated to take the spacing into consideration.

Comment: Yea thought so, but why its happening below row 2 only ? And in my code I've taken 'cellWd' for cell size as `CGSize(width:cellWd, height:cellWd)`

Comment: The pixels doesnt fit so it can happen on anywhere the internal calculations wants fit. I guess you have a device scale on 2x scale, thats why you see 1 pixel when u change it to 1.0 spacing , since 0.5/scale is 0.25pixels, it wont show on the screen. You could just do even better. make the spacing to = 0, and just change the height of the cell to   cellWd - (1.0f/scale) and you will get your spacing with perfect 1 pixel :) and just change the collectionview background you get the spacing color

Comment: as you said 'make the spacing to = 0' : this is removing space, irrespective of cell height.

Comment: @iAkki I have updated my answer with a formula. Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133271/discussion-between-hauzin-and-iakki).

Comment: That fixed it ! `floor` was the key. just changed sizeForItemAt to `return CGSize(width:cellWd, height:floor(cellWd) - 0.5)` and it worked. Thanks a lot !