# Remove inset spacing at bottom of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm really in need of some help here. I've been trying for a few days but can't seem to fix it...

I'm trying to lay out images in a `UICollectionView` grid style, with scrolling disabled. So I have 4 images/cells, and I'm trying to completely fill the `UICollectionView` with these images with 1 spacing between them.

**The problem**, however is that the spacing between the cells is split between center and the bottom.

I've noticed that when changing the `scrollDirection` of the UICollectionView from vertical to horizontal, the problem still exists, but just changes direction too, so I'm guessing it has something to do with that.

**example:**
[image]

code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if isInFeed && self.postImages!.count > 1 {

            guard let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
                return CGSize()
            }
            flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
            flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

            switch (self.postImages!.count) {

            case 2:
                // we split the collectionView into 2 parts (+ 2*0.5 spacing)
                return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.bounds.width/2)-CGFloat(0.5), height: self.collectionView!.bounds.height)

            case 3:

                // we split the collectionView into 3 parts, the first one taking up half, the other 2 images taking up 1/4th (+spacing)
                if indexPath.row == 0 { return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.bounds.width/2)-CGFloat(0.5), height: self.collectionView!.bounds.height) }
                else { return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.bounds.width/2)-CGFloat(0.5), height: (self.collectionView!.bounds.height/2)-CGFloat(0.5)) }

            case 4:
            // we split the collectionView into 4 parts (1/4th + spacing)


//                if indexPath.section == 0 { return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.bounds.width/2)-CGFloat(0.5), height: (self.collectionView!.bounds.height/2)-CGFloat(1))}
//                else {return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.bounds.width/2)-CGFloat(0.5), height: (self.collectionView!.bounds.height/2)-CGFloat(0))}

                return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView!.bounds.width/2)-CGFloat(0.5), height: (self.collectionView!.bounds.height/2)-CGFloat(0.5))

            default: break
            }
        }
        // If not in Feed or just one image, take up entire collectionView
        return CGSize(width: self.collectionView!.bounds.width, height: self.collectionView!.bounds.height)
    }
```

I also tried subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but without success, I've read Apple's documentation, but that doesn't seem to help much.

Hope this explains the problem clearly, I'd be happy to elaborate.
Have a great day!

**Edit:**

I changed the scroll direction from vertical to horizontal and added 2 extra calculated spacing to each cell just to show off what happens if I do that.

[image: example2]

**Edit 2:**

Finally managed to fix it! (altough not as clean as I'd like it, it does work now)
I put the following code inside of the `collectionViewLayout` method:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
     flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 1 * UIScreen.main.scale)
 } else {
     flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
 }
```

Big thanks to everyone trying to help out!

Comment: Take a look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675487/uicollectionviewflowlayout-minimumlinespacing-not-applied-to-whole-collection-vi/41675568#41675568 , this might give you the directions on how you should calculate spacing and item sizes. A hint is to make the spacing = 0. And calculate the "spacing" manually in the itemsize if you need spacing. Or the other way around as my answer.

Comment: @Sneak Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I tried out the UIScreen.main.scale as you said in your answer, but it didn't change anything. Also, I think I'm already calculating the extra spacing in the code I provided (unless I'm doing something wrong) I think the problem somehow has to do with the scrollDirection, because changing the scrolldirection changes the problem from horizontal to vertical axis too.

Comment: try my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580623/uicollectionview-doesnt-scroll-after-setting-contentinset/45582319#45582319

Comment: @solenoid Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check that part of the documentation when I have some time to work on it. :)

Comment: @JoniVr If you change the scrolldirection, the problem persist in the same way, but only changing positions according to the scrolldirection. The scrolldirection is not the issue, if you have no extra spacing, changing the direction wont matter, the spacing won't show up. The calculations are 100% the issue. Make sure you round down your results in your calculations, otherwise the delegate might end up showing extra **pixels** because the points is not rounded down correctly as you read in the comments in the solution I posted you.

Comment: @Sneak There should be enough spacing vertically (I think it's just spread out between the center and the bottom instead of just the center), If I want 1 spacing between cells horizontally and vertically, then setting + 0.5 extra space/cell should be enough, right? I did try adding more spacing and removing spacing before and it didn't seem to affect it (aside from adding even more spacing or not fitting the cell), but it didn't remove the spacing at the bottom, it's always split between center and bottom

Comment: @JoniVR See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution that worked for me (for anyone that runs into a similar situation):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if section == 0 {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 1 * UIScreen.main.scale)
    } else {
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you even see my answer? This does not solve your problem, it is just a bad compensation for the wrong calculated itemsizes you have for a specific section. This is section insets, and should not be used to compensate for itemspacing. Unless that is what you want to do of course.

Comment: I did see your answer and tried it too, but it didn't work, so I started trying some other things, the cellSize calculations should be right, if you have 2 cells taking up the space, and you want 1 spacing between them, then you should have collectionviewSize/2 - 0.5 per cell, right? I don't think the calculations were the issue... The spacing was applied to either the bottom/right (instead of between the sections/rows) depending on scollDirection. So I don't know if this is the correct way of doing this, but at least it works. If you have a better solution, I'd be happy to try and accept it.

Comment: @Sneak Also, what you suggested in your answer was the exact same thing as I did in my initial code (just using variables instead of values, which looks a bit cleaner), so I don't see why you would think the calculations were wrong when they were exactly the same as the ones you suggested (unless I'm wrong somewhere) :p

Comment: No worries mate, you are making this more complicated than it is :P I was worried about that , thats why I posted the screenshot. You can clearly see its perfectly clean with the calculations I made in the answer. Not sure why it didn't work for you, but I coded that and tested it and it works 100% well with different screen scales too. Anyways I am glad your solution works as long as it works thats the point. However, I recommend going with the clean way, even if it takes more time to get things right, patiance will give you alot of experience.

Comment: True, I do prefer doing things the right way, and I don't understand why it wasn't working, because I did the exact same thing you did lol. I read a lot of documentation and did lots of research and couldn't find a solution, so while it may not be clean (and I'm still not 100% satisfied) at least development can continue for now haha. Anyways, have a great day, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah I agree, you can always go back to it later :P I am not coding in Swift I am note sure why it does not work for you should be the same. Anways, GL Mate. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Add in a function and call in view did load. You might need to make a little adjustments but it works in my case.

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width / 2, height: width / 2)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, however I think that what you're suggesting will remove the spacing, right? I'm trying to get this grid layout with 1 spacing between the items (horizontally and vertically) and no spacing between the edges of the collectionViews. I did try the layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), but that didnt seem to help.

Comment: Yes that will remove the spacing. But what you want is possible from this code just add your required properties in it and you are good to go.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, I appreciate the effort, but this really doesn't help me at all then. I know how to remove the spacing, I need to get the spacing to go to the center instead of the bottom. I tried setting all insets/spacing to 0 (as you suggest here) and just adding the spacing in the cellSize, I tried tried the other way around and I tried them combined. Doesn't give me the result I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard try  with Size Inspector  with Minimum Spacing Zero and all Section Insects zero.

[image]

Comment: Everything in storyboard is set to 0, so this should not affect it, I don't like working with storyboard so much for this part, since it's a lot less easy to check/change. 
Thanks for trying to help though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0f;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0f;

CGSize collectionSize = collectionView.frame.size;
CGFloat cellsPerRow = 2.0f;
CGFloat spacing = 0.5f;

CGFloat itemWidth = collectionSize.width/cellsPerRow - spacing;
CGFloat itemHeight = collectionSize.height/cellsPerRow - spacing;

return CGSizeMake(itemWidth,itemHeight);
```

[image]